# In GCP, How to create a logs-based metric from logs in a different bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The new GCP Logs Viewer allows me to "Refine Scope" to a specific Logs Bucket:
[image]

However, if I try to do Actions->Create Metric it opens a new browser tab to Classic Logs Viewer, and I lose the original Scope context, so now it's looking at logs from the _Default bucket which is not what I want.
[image]

Comment: The new viewer is in beta, it smells like a bug. So, what do you want to achieve? How can I help you?

Comment: Please add more details what kind of metric you want to create (monitor only one bucket logs ??)

Comment: @Wojtek_B Yes I was looking to create a metric to monitor logs in a Log Storage Bucket that was not the _Default one.  See my answer posted below, at this time this is not supported yet.

Answer (score 2):

Discussed this with Google Cloud support person and they confirmed that at the time of this writing Metric Editor can only read logs from the _Default Log Storage Bucket.

So for now I'll route Logs to _Default and change to my preferred Log Storage Bucket when Metric Editor gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is still in alpha, the functionality of creating a log-based-metric on log buckets now available in [GCP log-based-metrics page](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/bucket-lbm).

For now, it is only doable via CLI and here is it command:

```
gcloud alpha logging metrics create METRIC_NAME \
      --description="METRIC_DESCRIPTION" \
      --log-filter="FILTER" \
      --bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME
```